# iPod Touch 9.3.5: Noting app that zeroes in/highlights the word upon search

Tags: notes.app

For months I've been trying to find a "Noting app that zeroes in/highlights the word upon search", but to no avail. Does someone perhaps know of any such app?

Comment: What exactly is a "Nothing" app? Where do you want to search in? Where did you actually try to find something which matches your needs?

Comment: Noting app, so sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the built-in Notes app. Choose Share → Find in Note, type in your search term and matches are highlighted. Use the up and down arrows to scroll to other matches.

[image]

Comment: It seems I can't do that in iOS 9.3.5, it also seems to be the final version for my iPod touch as it says "Your software is up to date". Do you perhaps know of any noting apps that might do that though? Have looked through dozen to no avail :^(